# What is the best best way to download and install msi\exe

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, drivers

I need to install drivers to my clients silently. 
Now, I have some issues:

1. I don't want to install them directly from the internet using Process.Start("www.......msi") beacuse it goes really slow. I want first to download them to the computer and then run a winform application to let the client choose which driver to install. 
   I tried the VS Installation but I couldn't figure out how to download all the "c:\Program Files" and NOT to the "Program files (x86)" in case of a windows  with 64 bits. 
   And I couldn't figure how to launch the winform app after the download complete, using the "custum action" didn't work.
2. I have different drivers for x86 and for x64, and I need to download to client's computer the drivers that he needs, how can I do that?
3. I have both msi and exe drivers, how can I install the exe driver silently?

If you know some third-party application I would be greatfull, this could be the best option for me!

Comment: Sounds like you have a plan and you know the steps required. Do you have any code so far?

Comment: I have all the msi driver installation done, considering I copy-paste manually the drivers to the Program Files and both x86 and x64 have the same name.

Comment: for your second question: you can check the pcs Osarchitcture with Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem (.Net 4 and later)and download the drivers bases on the result. For your first question: maybe use system variable %programfiles%

Comment: check MSI documentation there is a silent command i think it's as simple as `-s`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the answer in Visual Studio 2012 with the InstallShield and some programming work in my code.
Thank you all :)

Comment: Can you explain your solution?